# What parameters are possible in a data uri's mediatype?

Tags: javascript, data-uri

[The "data" URL scheme](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2397.txt) suggests a data uri can include optional parameters in the mediatype:

```
   dataurl    := "data:" [ mediatype ] [ ";base64" ] "," data
   mediatype  := [ type "/" subtype ] *( ";" parameter )
   data       := *urlchar
   parameter  := attribute "=" value
```

The [MSDN data uri page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28VS.85%29.aspx) also mentions them. The [MDN data uri page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs) does not.

Other than charset, what parameters are possible in a data uri's mediatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data URI's are similar to the content-type header. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.7. You can put any parameter you like in there, but most browsers probably only support charset.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter that goes in the mediatype is the mime type of the resource.

Read about mime types here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME

Read about data uris here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme